# Что нужно учесть при обработке персональных данных?

Tags: веб-программирование, юридические-аспекты, персональные-данные

Мне поступил заказ на создание веб приложения (в РФ) и один из пунктов ТЗ там загрузка сканов паспортов пользователей сайта. Я никогда до этого не сталкивался с обработкой персональных данных, подскажите какие нужно соблюсти формальности и нужно ли? Я имею ввиду формальности по типу подтверждений об обработки персональных данных или какие-то специальные протоколы обработки и шифрования. За этим нужно как-то или где-то отчитываться или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Наличие SSL
2. Текст о причинах сбора такой информации (должен предоставить заказчик)
3. Какие гарантии пользователя (должен предоставить заказчик)
4. Наличие личного серьезного юриста (для программиста)
5. Возможно потребуется аудит безопасности сторонней, аккредитованной
   организацией.
6. Еще раз подумай стоит ли оно таких рисков.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можете подсказать где более подробно изложены пункты 2 и 3? Также немного не понял пунктов 4 и 6 можете более подробно пояснить?

Comment: Главный источник
http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_61801/

Полезным будет
https://www.insales.ru/collection/doc-chasto-zadavaemye-voprosy/product/personalnye-dannye-informatsiya-dlya-vladeltsev-internet-magazinov

Если кратко:
1. Если есть какая-то форма, которая просит ФИО, мыло, телефон и т.д. - должна быть ссылка на текст политики. 
2. По требованию владельца данных - предоставить их ему. 
3. Третьим лицам не передавать, за исключением органам власти по решению суда.